# Yocto recipe problem with scons and ws281x on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, scons, meta-raspberrypi

I've got a problem creating a yocto (thud) recipe for the rpi_ws281x python module.
The machine itself is a raspberrypi3.

While building the recipe I get the following error:

```
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: python-rpi-ws281x-1.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.48175)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.48175
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| scons: Reading SConscript files ...
| scons: done reading SConscript files.
| scons: Building targets ...
| Version version.h
| CC      main.o
| CC      mailbox.o
| CC      ws2811.o
| CC      pwm.o
| CC      pcm.o
| CC      dma.o
| CC      rpihw.o
| AR      libws2811.a
| RANLIB  libws2811.a
| LINK    test
| scons: done building targets.
| running install
| running bdist_egg
| running egg_info
| creating rpi_ws281x.egg-info
| writing rpi_ws281x.egg-info/PKG-INFO
| writing top-level names to rpi_ws281x.egg-info/top_level.txt
| writing dependency_links to rpi_ws281x.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
| writing manifest file 'rpi_ws281x.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
| reading manifest file 'rpi_ws281x.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
| writing manifest file 'rpi_ws281x.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
| installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
| running install_lib
| running build_py
| creating build
| creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
| copying neopixel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
| running build_ext
| building '_rpi_ws281x' extension
| swigging rpi_ws281x.i to rpi_ws281x_wrap.c
| swig -python -o rpi_ws281x_wrap.c rpi_ws281x.i
| creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
| arm-ab-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native= -fPIC -I/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/python2.7 -c rpi_ws281x_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpi_ws281x_wrap.o
| arm-ab-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native= build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpi_ws281x_wrap.o -L../. -lws2811 -lrt -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_rpi_ws281x.so
| /home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/ld: .././libws2811.a: error adding symbols: file format not recognized
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| error: command 'arm-ab-linux-gnueabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.48175)
ERROR: Task (/home/user/git/poky-ab/meta-3rdparty/recipes-ws281x/python-rpi-ws281x.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1125 tasks of which 1118 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/user/git/poky-ab/meta-3rdparty/recipes-ws281x/python-rpi-ws281x.bb:do_compile
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

The recipe itself looks like this:

```
LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=9dcf340793a1d73c5211edc8238767dc"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x.git;protocol=https"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "b903b8342864ae8422039d4a7479ba4c"

SRCREV = "ba3b5bdad55dc7754567a68c4364b1e772735f47"

#DEPENDS += "python-setuptools-native swig-native python-scons-native"
DEPENDS += "swig-native python-scons"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit scons setuptools 

do_compile_prepend() {
    cd ${S}/
    scons
    cd ${S}/python/
    ${PYTHON} setup.py install
}
```

What I'm wondering about is that scons creates some binary code for linux-x86_64.
Is there any possibility that I can convice scons to use the exported Environment of Yocto?

Thanks in advance,

homer836

Comment: are you sure `libws2811.a` is for the right arch?

Comment: The ws2811 is just the controller of the chip of the led stripe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works.
I fixed the SContruct, created a patch and used the following recipe.

SConstruct:

```
#
# SConstruct
#
# Copyright (c) 2014 Jeremy Garff <jer @ jers.net>
#
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted
# provided that the following conditions are met:
#
#     1.  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of
#         conditions and the following disclaimer.
#     2.  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list
#         of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials
#         provided with the distribution.
#     3.  Neither the name of the owner nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse
#         or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
# 
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER BE
# LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
# (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA,
# OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
# CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT
# OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#


import os


opts = Variables()
opts.Add(BoolVariable('V',
                      'Verbose build',
                      True))

opts.Add('TOOLCHAIN',
         'Set toolchain for cross compilation (e.g. arm-linux-gnueabihf)',
         '')

platforms = [ 
    [
        'userspace',            # Target Name
        [ 'linux', 'version' ], # Scons tool (linux, avr, etc.)
        {                       # Special environment setup
            'LINKFLAGS' : [
                "-lrt",
            ],
        },
    ], 
]

cc_environment = os.environ['CC']
split_cc_environment_variable = cc_environment.split()
cc_bin = split_cc_environment_variable[0]
cc_parameters = split_cc_environment_variable[1:]

ld_env = os.environ['LD']
split_ld_env_variable = ld_env.split()
ld_bin = split_ld_env_variable[0]
ld_params = split_ld_env_variable[1:]

clean_envs = {}
for platform, tool, flags in platforms:
    env = Environment(
           options = opts,
           tools = tool,
           toolpath = ['.'],
           ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']},
       CC = cc_bin,
           LD = ld_bin,
           AR = os.environ['AR'],
           RANLIB = os.environ['RANLIB'],
           CCFLAGS = cc_parameters,
           LINKFLAGS = ld_params,
        LIBS = [],
    )

    env.MergeFlags(flags)
    clean_envs[platform] = env

Help(opts.GenerateHelpText(clean_envs))


Export(['clean_envs'])
SConscript('SConscript');
```

Recipe:

```
LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=9dcf340793a1d73c5211edc8238767dc"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x.git;protocol=https \
           file://0001-Patch-for-Yocto.patch"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "b903b8342864ae8422039d4a7479ba4c"

SRCREV = "ba3b5bdad55dc7754567a68c4364b1e772735f47"

DEPENDS += "swig-native python-scons"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit scons setuptools 

EXTRA_OESCONS += " CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT_IMPORT=True -mfl"

do_compile_prepend() {

export

    cd ${S}/
    scons
    cd ${S}/python/
    ${PYTHON} setup.py build
    ${PYTHON} setup.py install
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/python2.7
    cp ${S}/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/* ${D}${libdir}/python2.7/
}

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/python2.7/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I went and looked at the repo you are trying to build. This SConstruct looks like it expects some [TOOLCHAIN variable to be passed to it](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/blob/master/SConstruct#L38-L40):

```py
opts.Add('TOOLCHAIN',  
         'Set toolchain for cross compilation (e.g. arm-linux-gnueabihf)',  
         '')
```

Then later it uses that [to set the compiler](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/blob/master/SConstruct#L70-L72):

```
if env['TOOLCHAIN'] != '':
    env['CC'] = env['TOOLCHAIN'] + '-gcc'
    env['AR'] = env['TOOLCHAIN'] + '-ar'
```

SCons by default tries not to be dependent on the host environment. The SCons Environment must be setup in the SConstruct and SConscript files. This particular SConstruct does this by taking in the host PATH environment with os.environ['PATH'] and an alternate TOOLCHAIN option to setup the name of the compiler and linker to find in the path. This means the SConstruct is expecting your cross compiler to be in the PATH.

You can pass this [Variable to SCons from the command line](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idm2527):

```
do_compile_prepend() {
    cd ${S}/
    scons TOOLCHAIN=arm-ab-linux-gnueabi
    cd ${S}/python/
    ${PYTHON} setup.py install
}
```

Answer (score -1):

thank you for your reply.

One step further...
But now I encouter the following error:

```
ERROR: python-rpi-ws281x-1.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.3988)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.3988
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| scons: Reading SConscript files ...
| scons: done reading SConscript files.
| scons: Building targets ...
| CC      main.o
| In file included from main.c:33:
| /home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/include/stdint.h:9:16: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
|  # include_next <stdint.h>
|                 ^~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| scons: *** [main.o] Error 1
| scons: building terminated because of errors.
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/user/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.3988)
ERROR: Task (/home/user/git/poky-ab/meta-3rdparty/recipes-ws281x/python-rpi-ws281x.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

Is there any possibility to extend the std include path of scons?

```
user@smartbakery:~/git/poky-ab/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ab-linux-gnueabi/python-rpi-ws281x/1.0-r0$ find -name *.h|grep stdint
./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/include/stdint-gcc.h
./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/include/stdint.h
./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ab-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/plugin/include/config/glibc-stdint.h
./recipe-sysroot/usr/include/c++/8.2.0/tr1/stdint.h
./recipe-sysroot/usr/include/stdint.h
./recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/stdint-uintn.h
./recipe-sysroot/usr/include/bits/stdint-intn.h
```

It seems that the compiler does not find /recipe-sysroot/usr/include/stdint.h.

Best regards,
homer836

Comment: Asking a new question inside an answer that you give is somewhat counter-productive. Most people will see that the (original) question is already answered and don't bother to investigate things further. You probably want to open a new and separate question explicitly...

Comment: The SConsctuct in question does not provide a way to do that. I would expect some sort of sysroot option or similar to be passed on the command line if this SConstruct was intended to be used in cross compilation. Looking at the Readme in that repo, it seems this was intended to be built on the target.